# Add Google Contact via PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, google-api

I've successfully been able to add a contact to google through Zend Framework and PHP. I want to be able to do this through CURL as well. Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: I googled "google contact curl" and got [this](http://salmanzg.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/google-contact-data-api-via-curl/) which seems pretty thorough... Are you asking about command-line curl or php's curl functions?

Comment: I am asking about PHP's Curl functions, and I've googled a bunch with no luck. Thanks for the link I'll read through it too.

Comment: Asking recommendations for a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow, and this question is likely to be closed. Use Google's search engine for this. When you start implementing a solution and you run into a specific problem, you can always ask for help here. (as long as you follow [the guidelines on asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to do this via CURL and an access token. First, I would say that the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is very useful. There are 2 main components needed to do this: first, you need your XML formatted correctly. Secondly, you need your access token put into the header of the CURL instance. Below is the code I used, and it works just fine:

```
session_start();
$temp = json_decode($_SESSION['token'], true);
$access = $temp['access_token'];

$contactXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
<atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
<gd:name>
<gd:givenName>Jackie</gd:givenName>
<gd:fullName>Jackie Frost</gd:fullName>
<gd:familyName>Frost</gd:familyName>
</gd:name>
<gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" address="jackfrost@gmail.com"/>
<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true">1111111111</gd:phoneNumber>
</atom:entry>';

$headers = array(
'Host: www.google.com',
'Gdata-version: 3.0',
'Content-length: '.strlen($contactXML),
'Content-type: application/atom+xml',
'Authorization: OAuth '.$access
);

$contactQuery = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $contactQuery );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contactXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

I hope this helps anyone else who is looking for this answer. Playing around with the playground will help you find the right URLs to use and the right parameters required in the header.