# How Delete / update / Create Google Contacts API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying the Google Contacts API , i can retreive the contacts but i don't understand how must it be done for remove , create or delete with the API. i tried with a simple form but i have a error 401

```html
<?php
  }else{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
    var_dump($token->access_token);
    var_dump($client->getAccessToken());
    $curl = curl_init('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=50&access_token='.$token->access_token);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 10);
    $contact_json = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($contact_json);
    curl_close($curl) ;
    $contacts = json_decode($contact_json , true);
    var_dump( $contacts['feed']['entry'][7]);
    $monContact = $contacts['feed']['entry'][7];
    $monContactId =  $monContact['id']['$t'];



  }
 ?>
 <form class="" action="<?= $monContactId?>" method="DELETE">
   <input type="submit" name="name" value="DELETE">
 </form>
```

I tried just like that but I have no idea how to operate the thing .

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is so simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511385/add-google-contact-via-php-curl

Answer (score 1):

There is powerful Class which you can use it:
https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api

You can retrieve all contacts like this:

```
rapidweb\googlecontacts\factories\ContactFactory::getAll()
```

Or create Contact:

```
$name = "Frodo Baggins";
$phoneNumber = "06439111222";
$emailAddress = "frodo@example.com";

$newContact = rapidweb\googlecontacts\factories\ContactFactory::create($name, $phoneNumber, $emailAddress);
```

For more info check this blog post: http://www.rapidweb.biz/news/php-library-for-the-google-contacts-api-v3-06102593/

Comment: Yes , i seen but i want to learn with the Google library before and after i will use it

Comment: @SebastienTernisien check this page and you will find all in one place https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-contacts-v3-api/blob/master/factories/ContactFactory.php

Comment: Thanks for the shout out regarding our library! It might be worth updating your answer with the newer library we've created, which does the same thing, but it much easier to setup and use. https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api

Comment: This not works because no access_token exists, or not well documented. This works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511385/add-google-contact-via-php-curl